# Is there a word for this kind of figure of speech

Tags: figures-of-speech

Is there any specific name for this type of question or statement?

If I ask someone a yes/no type question

"Have you lost your mind?"

then either answer(yes or no) is degrading to the person replying.

No - ok you never had it.

Yes - could mean he has gone crazy.

There could also be a statement made to a person, which if that person refutes he is shown in bad light or even if he agrees, it is bad for him. Is there any name for such device?

Any examples of such devices(questions or statements) where I could read more of this type.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I don't think your example is particularly good. Answering "no" would not imply that I "never had it." A more common example is, "Do you still beat your wife?" Even answering "no" implies that there was a time the person did so.

Comment: I'd call it a [jacuzzi](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/j%27accuse).

Comment: @HotLicks *j'accuse* (Fr.)

Comment: @Kris - That's what I said.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You pointed to a duplicate?

Comment: Both the previous posts end with an accepted answer of "loaded question," which it is not. "Loaded" is too broad. (If a better answer is not forthcoming easily, that doesn't mean this is correct.)

Comment: @Kris I don't understand your question. // Of course ' a [question] made to a person, which if that person refutes he is shown in bad light or even if he agrees, it is bad for him. Is there any name for such device?' has the answer 'loaded question'. I'd say the first example is rather clumsy ('No - ok you never had it.').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your comment pointed to a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [loaded question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question).  The archetypal example is "have you stopped beating your wife?"

Comment: Please cite the source.

Comment: My comment above, I presume. -1 for no supporting reference (I consider this a duplicate, so didn't give an 'answer').

Comment: The correct question is, "Have you stopped beating your wife?  Yes or no?"

Comment: didn't see the comment, I think it wasn't here when I opened the page.  Just wanted to be helpful to OP.  Feel free to post a better answer than mine.  Or, alternatively, mark the question as a duplicate, whatever

Comment: It's just that "loaded question" is overly broad. As for the previous posts, the answerer is not the one to be faulted.